# How do I keep a copy of a formula in a column keeping one variable fixed?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How do I apply a formula to a whole column, keeping one variable fixed?
I.e

- 2nd row is `=AVERAGE(B1:B2)`,
- 3rd row is `=AVERAGE(B1:B3)`,
- 4th row is `=AVERAGE(B1:B4)`,
- etc...

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

*It's like getting running average, therefore I would like to suggest to use below shown formula.*

[image]

- Formula in `H58`:

`=AVERAGE($G$58:G58)`

*Where Column & Row doesn't change while filling down.*

it may be

`=AVERAGE(G$58:G58)`

*Where Row is not changing.*

As soon you fill it down Excel start getting average of

`G58:G58` (Row 1) then

`G58:G59` (Row 2)

and so to the 4th Row (H61) is `G58:G61`

Since absolute reference (using $ sigh) has been used with `G58`, works as fixed variable.

**N.B.**

If you use formula `=AVERAGE($G$58:G59)` as I've tried in `I58`, will works like,

`G58:G59` (Row 1)

`G58:G60` (Row 2)

`G58:G61` (Row 3)

gets Average of 1, 2, 3, 4 is `2.5`

as soon fill to the last row (I61),formula reads `G58:G62` , produces same value `2.5` since `G62` is Blank.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

Try following it hope it will work

2nd row is =AVERAGE($B$1:B2),
3rd row is =AVERAGE($B$1:B3),
4th row is =AVERAGE($B$1:B4),etc...